# Scrapy returning 302 for some network

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I'm getting 302 while scraping using scrapy in some specific network. It is working in my office network but not in my home network. It is working in my one mobile network but not working (getting 302)in another mobile network. Do you guys know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing which specific URL does it, I can only guess that those IP addresses that get a 302 might have been flagged by an anti-bot software solution and are being redirected to some kind of CAPTCHA.

Try [using Splash](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash), see if the results are the same.